# How to check whether a activity is foreground and bring it to background when it is foreground?

Tags: android, android-studio

I hope to define whether a activity is foreground in Android, and bring it to background when it is foreground. How can I do it?

You know the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>` is Deprecated!

**Sample Code**

```
private boolean isTopActivity(String activityName){
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfos = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
    String cmpNameTemp = null;
    if(runningTaskInfos != null){
        cmpNameTemp = runningTaskInfos.get(0).topActivity.toString();
    }
    if(cmpNameTemp == null){
        return false;
    }
    return cmpNameTemp.equals(activityName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is supported natively by the Activity lifecycle which is `onResume`, which will be called after the activity comes in the foreground.

```
public void onResume() {
    // do here what you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need to do it outside the Activity.

Comment: that is easy using the EventBus or the Observable

Comment: @KhalidTaha, could you please provide some examples using **EventBus** or **Observable**?

Comment: Sure, this is a tutorial of EventBus: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/effective-android-components-communication-with-greenrobot-eventbus--cms-27654

Comment: Thanks! How to get the  foreground activity ? could you show me some sample code?

Comment: inside the onResume of that activity, you can call the EventBus and pass the name of that activity, or the class of it. `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("the name of your activity"));`

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in a file in your application

```
    public class Foreground implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

public static final long CHECK_DELAY = 500;
public static final String TAG = Foreground.class.getName();

public interface Listener {

    public void onBecameForeground();

    public void onBecameBackground();

}

private static Foreground instance;

private boolean foreground = false, paused = true;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener>();
private Runnable check;

/**
 * Its not strictly necessary to use this method - _usually_ invoking
 * get with a Context gives us a path to retrieve the Application and
 * initialise, but sometimes (e.g. in test harness) the ApplicationContext
 * is != the Application, and the docs make no guarantees.
 *
 * @param application
 * @return an initialised Foreground instance
 */
public static Foreground init(Application application) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Foreground();
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(instance);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Application application) {
    if (instance == null) {
        init(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Context ctx) {
    if (instance == null) {
        Context appCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        if (appCtx instanceof Application) {
            init((Application) appCtx);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised and " +
                        "cannot obtain the Application object");
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised - invoke " +
                        "at least once with parameterised init/get");
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean isForeground() {
    return foreground;
}

public boolean isBackground() {
    return !foreground;
}

public void addListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    paused = false;
    boolean wasBackground = !foreground;
    foreground = true;

    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    if (wasBackground) {
        Log.i(TAG, "went foreground");
        for (Listener l : listeners) {
            try {
                l.onBecameForeground();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    paused = true;

    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    handler.postDelayed(check = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (foreground && paused) {
                foreground = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "went background");
                for (Listener l : listeners) {
                    try {
                        l.onBecameBackground();
                        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
                        if (intent != null) {
                            // We found the activity now start the activity
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.package.name"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exc) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
            }
        }
    }, CHECK_DELAY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
}
```

Now in onCreate method of Application.class put the code:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Foreground.init(this);
}
```

You can now use `Foreground.isBackground()` to get application is in background or not.

You can even perform specific task in one of the overridden lifecycle methods (onActivityPaused, onActivityStopped etc)